# How can I create a REST API client for a Windows Runtime project in Visual Studio / by external tools?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime, swagger, windows-10-iot-core

In Visual Studio for .net projects I can use built in tools to generate API clients by swagger. It simply and works great.

This option is missing from Windows Runtime projects as well, like Windows 10 IOT ones.

What is the best way to create API clients by swagger for this? If there is no built in tool / extension for VS, any external tools are highly appriciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you check [Restfar](https://github.com/forehalo/Restfar) or [HttpClient sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient)?

Comment: Thanks Rita. HttpClient works of course, but I have to implement it myself with several hours of work instead of doing it automatically by a click, like I used to in my .net projects.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4822#issuecomment-285920432) ? It seems [someone @ncksol](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4822#issuecomment-287387914) test it and works.

Comment: I looked at it, but I can't find what programming language language should I set as parameter. I git cloned the latest version etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question completely; on Windows IOT Core you can run UWP (background) apps; they are compatible with .net framework and .net standard up to version 1.4. This should work with a generated client from swagger.

Also you can use [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) to create a REST client according to best practices based upon an interface with attribute decorations.

Comment: It misses Microsoft.Rest library, IServiceOperations interface, HttpOperationResponse, ServiceClientTracing classes and so on. There are no equialent libs, classes on this platform (or I could not find it)

Comment: Did you try Refit?